# Setting a value to an enum in same namespace but different class? C++

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

**EDIT**
Thanks to comments under the question, I realized that you have to declare an enum in the header file also. >.< Why does nothing on the internet about enums mention this?
Now the compiler is recognizing Geologist.

My enum is within `namespace Star` in a class called `GameModeState` but I need to check the current enum value within a class called `ZoneMovementState`, which is also using `namespace Star`. I have GameModeState included at the top of ZoneMovementState.
The enum declaration in GameModeState is this:

```
enum Job {Landman = 0, Geologist = 1};
```

I'm trying to use this code in ZoneMovementState:

```
int placeholderJob = Star::GameModeState::Geologist;
//or I've tried this
int placeholderJob = GameModeState::Geologist;
```

For some reason my compiler is not recognizing Geologist in either attempt; how do I set `placeholderJob` to Geologist?

Comment: Is Job declared as public? What is the exact error message of your compiler?

Comment: Describing the code in English (a very convoluted language full of double meanings a cultural differences) is usually a bad idea. Show actual code. Languages like C++ are designed to be interpreted in one way. So show the appropriate code and the error message. Preferably a piece of code we can compile and get the same error message.

Comment: did you create the enum in private or protected section of GameModeState?

Comment: The actual error message would be useful. I'm also curious why your code doesn't look like `GameModeState::Job placeholderJob = Geologist;` (although I don't know if that would work either).

Comment: No error message. It simply won't find Geologist. i.e I type Geologist and it wants to me to create something named Geologist instead of recognizing that it is an enum name in GameModeState

Comment: GameModeState::Job::Geologist?

Comment: GameModeState::Job::Geologist is wrong, you don't need to add the enum name

Comment: <quote>No error message. It simply won't find Geologist.</quote> Its either an error (with a message) or not. If it can't find something then there must be an error (or it would find it and you would not know there was a problem).

Comment: Briz: Perhaps your editor/IDE is shitty. try to compile anyway. Then give us the error message.

Comment: it's fixed apparently (see edit)

Comment: See the Edit in the question. The problem was due to the enum not being declared at all in the header file of GameModeState.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it not recognize Geologist in the scope of your program? (When you mouse over does intellisense pop up and show you that Geologist is an enum type equal to 1) or does it have a squigly underneath it (indicating it does not recognize the type?)

This could be a scoping issue (although based on your information it doesn't sound like it), or perhaps the compiler you are using does not allow setting the value of an enumeration to an integer without an explicit cast.

Comment: It was showing the red squiggly. I had not declared the enum in the header file. T_T

Comment: Yup, just saw the other comments :)  I was late as usual.

Comment: I chose your answer because you were nice, and actually asked specifics about what the problem was rather than asking for the "error message". To me that could mean what my compiler is throwing up when I try to compile my code, and I wasn't compiling.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does nothing on the internet about enums mention this?

The internet doesn't need to mention this, because it groks compilation units.

Header files are there to tell a compiler (basically) what names (*identifiers*) exist and what they represent. This is why the compiler tells you when he doesn't know what a Geologist represents.

The same goes for functions, fields, classes, structs, typedefs, namespaces, so really the question would be

> Why would a compiler magically know about enums in another compilation unit, when everything else has to be spelled out for him?